# Use date and/or strtotime() functions in php to identify complex date patterns

Tags: php

I am well versed in using strtotime or the date modify functions within PHP to find NEXT or PREVIOUS days/months/years, or to add or subtract dates.  There is the ability to do something like `strtotime("first day of last month")` but there is not the ability to use a specific month name (let's say July) as a parameter...so it seems I cannot say `strtotime("first day of last July")`.

My question is NOT

> "can you write me some code to give me the date"

but rather

> "is there a streamlined 1 or 2 line approach using strtotime() or
>   something else that will enable me to reach the same output with
>   something more compact, tidy, and clear?"

I am trying to streamline some fairly clunky code to figure out the date (really just the year) of July 1 two instances ago...not the most recent past July 1, but the one a year prior to that (so it could be a date almost 2 full years in the past...or could be as recent as 1 year and 1 day in the past).

For example:

> Assume today is February 26, 2014. I am trying to output 2012-07-01.
>   However a bit later this same year... let's say on July 2 of 2014...
>   the output would now be 2013-07-01

So, essentially I need to figure out if July 1 has already happened in the current year...and if not then subtract 2 from the current year...and if yes, then subtract 1 from the current year.

A clunky version looks like this:

```
$CurrentDate = date("Y-m-d");
$CurrentYear = date("Y");
$ThisYearCutOff = $CurrentYear.'-07-01';
if($CurrentDate > $ThisYearCutOff){
    echo ($CurrentYear-1).'-07-01';
}
else
{
    echo ($CurrentYear-2).'-07-01';
}
```

Any thoughts on how to do this in a relatively streamlined bit of php code?

Comment: An alternative I can think of is to initially set your date to July 1st from 2 years ago. Then you use `date_diff()` to check if the difference with today is more than 2 years. If yes, you add 1 year to the initial result. But of course it's not much more streamlined than what you had.

Comment: That is an interesting approach...I suppose that would cut one or two lines.  Anyone else have anything better?